# Why is boric acid soapy to touch?

Tags: organic-chemistry, inorganic-chemistry, acid-base

Bases are soapy to touch because of soap formation on contact with lipids present on our skin. If this is the case then why and how is boric acid soapy to touch?

Comment: @DGS            Yeah , but how H3BO3 is self lubricating?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

From what I've been able to find, it is similar to how graphite acts as a lubricant. Boric acid is flat and it hydrogen bonds to form layers of flat networks. These slide on each other like layers of graphite do, reducing friction.